# instance_variable_get returns nil when it's an empty string

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I use `mail`, `nokogiri`, and `reverse_markdown` gems to read an email and process the body, stripping out external tags and a unicode zero width character (`u200b`) to get an instance variable `@body` that refers to a string. Here's the relevant code:

```
@body = email.html_part.decoded.delete("\u200b")
@body = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(@body).at("div")
@body.css("br").each { |node| node.replace('<br />') }
@body.css("div").each { |node| node.replace(node.inner_html)}
@body = @body.inner_html
@body = ReverseMarkdown.convert(@body)
if @body.gsub(/\s+/, "").length == 0
  unless email.attachments.length > 0
    raise StandardError, "Empty email"
  end
end
puts @body.class # => "String"
```

After `ReverseMarkdown.convert`, the empty email is still three characters long, likely due to whitespace from stripping out tags, or because the Markdown converter forces it to have a whitespace with two spaces. That's why I do `gsub` length check to strip out white spaces.

When I run my rspec test:

```
context 'with no body' do
  it 'outputs the body to markdown' do
    puts instance_variable_get(:@body).class # => 'NilClass'
    expect(instance_variable_get(:@body)).to eq("")
  end
end
```

when the email is empty and has no attachments, it shows:

```
expected: ""
got: nil
```

I can't imagine why the class of the variable changes.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified a receiver for `instance_variable_get`, so it will default to `self` which here is an RSpec example group.

You would need `email.instance_variable_get(:@body)` (assuming your `subject` is `email`).

**However**: using methods such as `instance_variable_get` in a test is a danger signal. You should aim to test a class by its public interface, not by examining its internals.

Comment: What if I'm not using the method on a class?  Is that required?  When I tried this I got: `undefined local variable or method 'email'`  **Note** I should probably specify, I'm trying out BDD for the first time, so I'm just trying to get the tests to pass here.  I'm not sure if I'm going to be using a class later or not because it's a wee tiny little program and Mail handles the email class pretty handily.

Comment: Within the context of the example 'email' will refer to a locally defined variable. You need to define it using `let`, or by assigning a value to it in the example. You *may* be able to use `subject` if your `describe` block specifies the class that you are testing, e.g. `describe MyClass`. You haven't shown enough code for us to know what is really going on here.